# Numpy unique function

Tags: python, numpy

I have a quick question about the numpy `unique` function. I want to return the unique column values for each row

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3],
              [3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
              [3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1]]) # a.shape is (3,16)



np.unique(a)
array([1, 2, 3]) # not what I want

np.unique(a,axis=1)
array([[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3]]) # also not what I want, and I'm not even sure what its doing

np.apply_along_axis(np.unique,1,a)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]]) # this is what I want
```

The problem is that I also want to use other features of `np.unqiue`, like returning index values. Can anyone help me to get `np.unique` to work by itself?

Comment: For what it's worth you can use the parameters of `unique()` with `apply_along_axis()`, it just won't be super clean.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over rows and collect unique values:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3],
              [3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
              [3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1]])

arr = np.empty((0,3), int)
for row in a:
    arr = np.append(arr, np.array([np.unique(a)]), axis=0)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]]
```

Comment: Is this better than `np.apply_along_axis(np.unique,1,a)` ?

Answer (score 0):

numpy will not be able to return a matrix with rows of different sizes.  your example has exactly 3 distinct values per row which makes np.apply_along_axis work but if you had a value of 4 in one of the rows or only 1s and 2s on a row it would fail.

To obtain what you are looking for you will need to use a normal Python list as the result.  You can build it using a list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1],
              [3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
              [3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1]]) 

r = [ np.unique(row) for row in a ]
print(r)
# [array([1, 2]), array([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 2, 3, 4])]

r = [ np.unique(row,return_index=True)for row in a ]
print(r)
# [(array([1, 2]), array([0, 1])), 
#  (array([1, 2, 3]), array([11,  1,  0])), 
#  (array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([14,  3,  0,  6]))]
```

One thing you could do is build a mask of the values that are the first of their kind on each row.  This can be done using numpy.

Here's one way to do it (hopefully, numpy experts could suggest something less convoluted):

```
np.sum(np.cumsum(np.cumsum(a==np.unique(a)[:,None,None],axis=2),axis=2)==1,axis=0)

array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Such a mask offers many processing options such as finding indices of the first occurrence on each line (using np.argwhere), erasing/assigning first or subsequent occurrences, and more.